# Parallel shell execution and parameters

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-parallel

I'm monitoring a folder which is receiving log files.
For each log file received, I need to send it to a remote server via SCP. SCP transfer is done via **transfer.sh** script.
Since I need to perform a transfer for each file, its probable that a single file may delay other new files. I would like to "create" a new **parallel** process for each file in my directory.

```
MONITOR_FOLDER='/repository/'
PATTERN='log_*'

    for log_file in $MONITOR_FOLDER$PATTERN     
        do              
            echo "$(date +%c) monitor() Processing $log_file CDR file..."
            parallel --will-cite -n0 "sh transfer.sh $log_file 1" ::: {1..1}
        done
```

the $MONITOR_FOLDER$PATTERN can return 0 or more files.
When there is more than 1 file, I want to create a parallel process per file.
The following command display the correct list.

```
ls $MONITOR_FOLDER | grep 'log_*'
```

Question:

1) For each entry use it as param for my shell script and at the same time create a new process **without** the loop

Comment: Why not just run the command in the background by appending `&` to it?

Comment: Your greatest bottleneck is the network. Opening a parallel connection to the same server won't alleviate that. (In fact, multiple connections will have more overhead.)

Comment: However, you could try gzipping the file locally, piping it through ssh, and then ungzip it on the remote end. That may be faster or slower. YMMV.

Comment: @jpaugh You can just enable SSH compression.

Comment: See https://wiki.ncsa.illinois.edu/display/~wglick/Parallel+Rsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm monitoring a folder which is receiving log files.
>   For each log file received, I need to send it to a remote server via SCP. SCP transfer is done via **transfer.sh** script.

That part is easy:

```
MONITOR_FOLDER='/repository/'
PATTERN='log_*'

parallel -j0 'echo "$(date +%c) monitor() Processing {} CDR file..."; sh transfer.sh {} 1' ::: $MONITOR_FOLDER$PATTERN
```

Or:

```
ls $MONITOR_FOLDER | grep 'log_*' | parallel -j0 'echo "$(date +%c) monitor() Processing {} CDR file..."; sh transfer.sh {} 1'
```

> Since I need to perform a transfer for each file, its probable that a single file may delay other new files. I would like to "create" a new **parallel** process for each file in my directory.

This is also easy if you allow for a file to be copied more than once and to have as many scp's running as there are files. Simply add & to the command:

```
MONITOR_FOLDER='/repository/'
PATTERN='log_*'

for log_file in $MONITOR_FOLDER$PATTERN       
    do              
        echo "$(date +%c) monitor() Processing $log_file CDR file..."
        sh transfer.sh $log_file 1 &
    done
```

Now it gets more tricky if:

- You at most want 12 scp's running at the same time
- You only want to copy a file once

But you can probably use this: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-GNU-Parallel-as-dir-processor

```
notifywait -q -m -r -e MOVED_TO -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f $MONITOR_FOLDER |\
grep 'log_*' | parallel -j12 'echo "$(date +%c) monitor() Processing {} CDR file..."; sh transfer.sh {} 1'
```

It will just sit there waiting for a new file to be written. So if you want to stop it, you will have to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your code :

```
 for log_file in $MONITOR_FOLDER$PATTERN
```

Please go through the loop process and study how loop works, in your case `for`

For e.g.

```
 for i in '1 2 3 4 5'     # it will iterate from 1 to 5
```

but

```
  for i in $VAR    # it will iterate over `echo $VAR` means its value
```

Thus in your case the variable log_file will get first value as `/repository/log_*` but not its content.

To make your code working you may do like.

```
 for log_file in `ls $MONITOR_FOLDER$PATTERN`
```